# Scapy WPA2 packet forging

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, packet, wpa2

Can I use scapy to forge custom packets on WPA2 network? Can I even pack the IEEE 802.11 headers? I have access to the WPA2 passphrase so will there be something stopping me from doing it?

Answer (score 1):

WPA2 uses AES-CCMP. CCMP stands for Counter-mode CBC-MAC Protocol. CBC-MAC means Cipher Block Chaining Message Authentication Codes. Those Message Authentication Codes (MACs) protect against forgeries and replays.

I'm not sure, but I think that even if you have the network's WPA2 passphrase and SSID, which lets you know derive the PSK (Pre-Shared Key) which is the PMK (Pairwise Master Key), and even if you capture the WPA2 handshake when a client joins so you get the nonces that would let you determine that client's PTK (Pairwise Temporal Key) and the rest of the key hierarchy, I think those CBC-MACs would still make it hard to forge frames as if they came from that client (or forge frames from the AP to that client, as if they came from the AP).

Said another way:
Knowing the WPA2-PSK passphrase and the network's SSID, and then capturing the target client's WPA2 handshake when it (re)joins the network, is enough to let you *decrypt* the traffic in either direction between that client and the AP. But I think the CBC-MACs would still make it difficult to forge or even replay packets between those two devices. But I could be wrong on this point.

I'm trying to answer whether or not it's theoretically possible given the security protocols. A separate question is whether or not scapy contains code to do this for you. I'm not very familiar with scapy, so I can't answer that part for you. But if scapy has the code to forge the CBC-MACs, it's probably a good indication that it's possible on WPA2-PSK networks.

WPA2-Enterprise (with 802.1X) is another story, because WPA2-Enterprise creates new PMKs every time a client (re)joins, so even if you capture the target client's WPA2 handshake, you don't have the information you need to derive the key hierarchy and decrypt that client's traffic.

Comment: What about exploiting the hole196 vulnerability whereby I can use the group key to encrypt data. That should be straight forward